# The cultural effect of torture, imprisionment and war in a community

Tags: society, warfare, culture, people

So, I've been writing about a planet called Tabor, a tidally locked earth-like planet with harsh conditions that humanity decided to use as a prison for political and religious criminals.

To summarize, the soon to be Taborians were imprisoned for challenging the rule of the Pondering One, humanity's leader. They were subject to gruesome torture, but at the same time being left alive for the sake of prolonging their suffering for an abnormal time period. When they managed to escape and defeat their captors, they were forced to fight further, more for their liberty.   Many men saw first hand the true horrors of war, despite all the odds against them they won, but at the cost of almost total solitude. They won shortly after humanity was destroyed by an alien coalition that wanted to destroy the Pondering One along with his servants.

I was wondering about how they would build their own Taborian cultural identity. I first thought of "transcending the pain to become everlasting" as a common concept for them. The philosophy of them centered around death, memory, accepting one's fate calmly, learning from suffering and others things, but I would love to hear about real life examples of how the culture of a community evolves after a long period of instability, violence or war.

Comment: In general asking "What would be the effect of X on a culture" is too broad a question for this site. Can you [edit] this to ask something more specific?

Comment: This question  fails the "book test": *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*

Comment: Please learn how to write. Paragraphs improve readability. Walls of text are not easy to read. Also, you use commas where you should be using periods (full stops). People need to breath when they read. The use of periods allows that. As originally written, your question either leaves readers gasping for air or having to break where convenient for them to breath, thus destroying the flow of the prose. I edited your question to make it easier to read. It took some effort.

Comment: Harsh conditions do not automatically lead to great prison locations. The USA's most famously notorious prison --it's place of uttermost punishment-- was not in the frozen arctic nor the barren southwest deserts nor the hot, humid, alligator-infested swamps of southern Florida. It was in San Francisco bay with a pleasant climate and a million-dollar panoramic view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the personality traits which would thrive on this world prior to the prison's fall; these traits will likely be present in the heroes of the revolution and will therefore likely become the cornerstones of your new "culture".

Given a mutual enemy in the guards and torturers, the prisoners will naturally congregate into groups. These groups will either be lead by a great warrior or a great negotiator/healer.  For most of the life of the prison, healer leaders will have the upper hand since the warrior's path to open rebellion is impractical prior to the alien attack which destroys the guard's supply lines.  Until they became outnumbered and under-equipped, the guards will always too tough to confront directly.  Hot heads might occasionally try, but each of their failures would add to the healer leaders' ranks.

So healer leadership thrived throughout the prison's history, until at last, a warrior rose up and won, ushering in a short, brutal phase where the victorious warlord and his forces replaced the guards.

But great warriors make poor farmers and the prison world is far from self sufficiency.  The lack of supplies made the rebellion possible, but that same deficiency will undermine any leadership borne of brute force.  In quick order, the intellectuals, agrarians and artisans will rise to power, saving the new civilization from the jaws of starvation.

My point in telling this dark tale is that culture is a luxury which evolves during times of peace. The lean years after a rebellion (and a collapse of the galactic economy/infrastructure) are anything but peaceful.

You may see pockets of inherited culture surrounding individual leaders; beliefs and rituals borrowed from the religions or political views that got them arrested long ago, but the majority of your civilization's attention will be dedicated to extracting necessities out of the undeveloped planet's scarcity.  Survival will be the only proof of wisdom needed during the initial dark decades.